# wallet for hybrid mobile application

Tags: android, ios, api, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm trying to make a hybrid mobile application using PhoneGap (html, css, JavaScript) and i'm planning to add payment feature to the application, it should generate a QR code that contains user's information (regarding payment-the amount, the service that he's paying for), this wallet also should provide a QR code that shows a certain document for the user once it's get scanned.

I have been searching for wallet/passbook (which is available for ios only) but I didn't find a plugin that is suitable for both.

I will be thankful if anyone could provide me with information on how to solve this issue.

Comment: I guess the question wasn't clear as there might some confusion between the two requirement, I'm looking for a plugin similar to wallet/passbook but it should be for both ios and android, it must generate a QR code for the user and when it gets scanned it should show a certain document (pdf, picture) or just some information about the user.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this help or not. I found the following 2 options

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-payment-plugin

https://github.com/ToastWallet/core

Comment: Thank you, please refer to my comment above as I think that my question wasn't clear.